# Adding information to a file using data from other file

Tags: awk

I would like to add all information for file1 in each record for file2.

In the output file should be 5 lines for each record on file1 ( populated from file1)

**file1**

```
21000,10000,20000
21024,10000,20000
21048,10000,20000
21072,10000,20000
21096,10000,20000
```

**file2**

```
41078,15525
41072,15527
41074,15529
```

**output desired**

```
41078 15525 21000 10000 20000
41078 15525 21024 10000 20000
41078 15525 21048 10000 20000
41078 15525 21072 10000 20000
41078 15525 21096 10000 20000
41072 15527 21000 10000 20000
41072 15527 21024 10000 20000
41072 15527 21048 10000 20000
41072 15527 21072 10000 20000
41072 15527 21096 10000 20000
41074 15529 21000 10000 20000
41074 15529 21024 10000 20000
41074 15529 21048 10000 20000
41074 15529 21072 10000 20000
41074 15529 21096 10000 20000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Cyrus, he is already a member since 5 years as his profile says

Comment: @Mihir: Then the rules of SO should be known.

Comment: @Cyrus, If you don’t mind me asking, shouldn’t the question be flagged because going as per the OP profile, this question asking pattern has been repeated since the time he joined.

Comment: @Mihir idk if a flag is the right thing or not but it deserves some kind of feedback since there's not even an attempt at solving it from the OP after asking and getting answers to 63 previous awk questions, many of them very similar to this one.

Comment: @EdMorton, yea I tried to flag but no option matches the scenario. So it would be best if it gets some moderators attention maybe?

Comment: @Mihir I'd just downvote and vote to close it if I were you, you've already commented here on why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F"," 'FNR==NR {a[++t]=$1" "$2" "$3;next} {for (i=1;i<=t;i++) print $1,$2,a[i]}  ' file1 file2
41078 15525 21000 10000 20000
41078 15525 21024 10000 20000
41078 15525 21048 10000 20000
41078 15525 21072 10000 20000
41078 15525 21096 10000 20000
41072 15527 21000 10000 20000
41072 15527 21024 10000 20000
41072 15527 21048 10000 20000
41072 15527 21072 10000 20000
41072 15527 21096 10000 20000
41074 15529 21000 10000 20000
41074 15529 21024 10000 20000
41074 15529 21048 10000 20000
41074 15529 21072 10000 20000
41074 15529 21096 10000 20000
```

Shorten some:

```
awk -F"," '{$1=$1} FNR==NR {a[++t]=$0;next} {for (i=1;i<=t;i++) print $0,a[i]}  ' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line; do
  awk '{print '${line}', $0}' < file1;
done < file2 | sed 's/,/ /g'
```

For each line of file2, print every line of file1 and prepend the line from file2. Also replace commas by spaces.

Comment: You should not use external variable within awk code.  Change it to some like this `awk -v var=$line '{print var, $0}' < file1;`

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).